# A question about weak convergence on the unit ball of a reflexive space

Tags: banach-spaces

Which class of reflexive spaces $X$ having the property: if a sequence $(x_{n})_{n}\subset B_{X}$ converges to $x$ weakly and $\|x_{n}\|\rightarrow 1$, then the norm of $x$ must be 1. Of course, the classical sequence spaces $l_{p}$ do not have this property.It seems that this condition is too strong.

Comment: For starters, I think no separable reflexive Banach space can have this property.  It seems to be pretty straightforward to show that for any separable Banach space $Y$, there is a sequence $f_n \in Y^*$ with $\|f_n\| = 1$ and $f_n \to 0$ weakly-*.  (Use the Hahn-Banach theorem to make $f_n$ which vanish on more and more elements of a countable dense subset of $X$.)  So if $X$ is reflexive we can apply this with $Y = X^*$.  Also of course, there are non-reflexive spaces with this property, like $l_1$ or any other space with Schur's property.

Comment: You are right, Nate. $S_{X^{*}}$ is $weak^{*}$ sequentially dense in $B_{X^{*}}$ for every infinite-dimensional space $X$.

Comment: There are of course spaces with this property: this works (trivially) when weak convergence implies norm convergence, as in finite dimensional spaces $X$ and $X=\ell^1$ (which is not reflexive).

Comment: @DongyangChen: I did not quite see how to do the non-separable case, but if you do, then it seems your question is resolved.  You can post an answer for it yourself.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Since $S_{X^{*}}$ is $weak^{*}$ sequentially dense in $B_{X^{*}}$ for every infinite-dimensional space $X$(see J.Diestel, Sequences and series in Banach spaces. page.223,Exercise 2), there is a sequence $(x^{*}_{n})_{n}\in S_{X^{*}}$ such that $x^{*}_{n}$ converges to zero $weak^{*}$ly. If $X$ is reflexive, then $x^{*}_{n}$ converges to zero weakly.

Comment: @DongyangChen: Indeed.  The part I was not sure about is how to prove that $S_{X^*}$ is weak-* **sequentially** dense in $B_{X^*}$, when $X$ is not separable (showing it is weak-* dense is easy) - the rest follows as you say.  But I can take a look at Diestel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the following space which is called Grothendieck space may be partial answer for your question.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_space

Comment: Certainly not. Every reflexive space is Grothendieck, yet don't satisfy the assumption.

Comment: You are right, Denis. Every infinite-dimensional reflexive space is Grothendieck, yet does not satisfy my question.

Comment: Since $S_{X^{*}}$ is $weak^{*}$ sequentially dense in $B_{X^{*}}$ for every infinite-dimensional space $X$(see J.Diestel, Sequences and series in Banach spaces. page.223,Exercise 2), there is a sequence $(x^{*}_{n})_{n}\in S_{X^{*}}$ such that $x^{*}_{n}$ converges to zero $weak^{*}$ly. If $X$ is reflexive, then $x^{*}_{n}$ converges to zero weakly. Thus, my question is false. Sorry!